# Insert or update counter value then returning the counter value in single statement

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite 3.8, without upsert support: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE "data" (
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "counter" INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_index ON data (name);
```

I was able to insert or update the counter by using the following way.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO data
VALUES ("the name",
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT counter FROM data
       WHERE name="the name"),
    0) + 1);
```

However, I would also like to able to return the newly inserted (or increased) counter in single statement.

I am doing it in 2 statements, which can cause race condition in multithread app.

### 2 statements

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO data
VALUES ("the name",
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT counter FROM data
       WHERE name="the name"),
    0) + 1);

SELECT counter FROM data where name="the name";
```

Is it possible to perform all within 1 statement?

Comment: Can't you use `last_insert_rowid()` to obtain the new created identity?

Comment: In the above example, we are interested in `counter` column.

Comment: Understood, it's not an identity column, apologies

Comment: No, you can't do it in a single statement.

Comment: "No, you can't" is a risky answer on StackOverflow, but with a good explanation can also be absolutely great. @forpas

Comment: @Yunnosch the comment is: "No, you can't do it in a single statement" and not "No, you can't" and it is self explanatory.

Comment: "No, you can't do it in a single statement" as helpfully an answer to "Is it possible to perform all within 1 statement?" as "No, you can't". Both explain equally helpfully about the reasons for the impossibility; not at all. @forpas

Comment: @Yunnosch if you can't understand what my comment means I can't help you.

Comment: I think your comment is very clear. At least I can only imagine two meanings. One is "I know a convincing reasoning why this is impossible, but won't tell you." The other is "I cannot think of a way to do that." So the meaning is as clear as it needs to be to give an impression of being not helpful. @forpas

Comment: @Yunnosch *At least I can only imagine two meanings* try harder.

Comment: @forpas No. But feel free to descibe another meaning which makes your comment appear in a helpful light. Then I would be willing to apologise and admit that the misunderstanding was my mistake.